# yocto built tool chain search path issue

Tags: gcc, yocto

I have built images for IMX6 using two different yocto versions.  Following are the details.

### Yocto Version1:

```
    #curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
    #repo init -u git://git.freescale.com/imx/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp.git -b imx-3.10.53-1.1.0_ga
    #repo sync
    #bitbake core-image-minimal
```

### Yocto Version2:

```
    #curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
    #repo init -u git://git.freescale.com/imx/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp.git -b imx-3.14.52-1.1.0_ga
    #repo sync
    #bitbake core-image-minimal
```

Tool chain tree structure for both versions of yocto update @ http://pastebin.com/Jx7HtANR

I have compiled following sample program using both tool chains built using two different yocto versions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    return 0; 
}
```

But tool chain built using yocto version 2 is giving following error.

```
test.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

Tool chain built using yocto version 1 is searching for header files under 
**"build/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/include"**, but tool chain built using yocto version 2 is not searching for header files under **"build/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/include"**, so it is giving error.

Can you help, why tool chain built using yocto version 2 is not searching for header files under **"build/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd/usr/include"**.

Where to change the tool chain configuration in yocto to include the above mentioned search path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer versions, OpenEmbedded based build systems, poisons the built in sysroot definition in the generated cross-compiler. The reason is that we'd like to detect applications that aren't respecting the the cross-compiling environment.

The solution is to not use `${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc` directly, but instead use `$CC`.  `$CC`, when set by the environment setup script from the generated SDK, will add the correct sysroot argument.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not able to understand what exactly meant by "poisons the built in sysroot definition in the generated cross-compiler".  
I am using the yocto cross compiled tool chain to compile the 3rd part source. The 3rd party source exporting the variables as shown @ http://pastebin.com/jWjHnC53 . Can you guide where exactly I need to replace "${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc" with $CC. i.e in the yocto metadata or while compiling the 3rd party application. If so what I have to give for $CC.

Comment: By poisoning, it is meant that the real sysroot is replaced by a fake path (that doesn't exist). Thus, you're forced to add `--sysroot=...` to all your calls to `gcc` and friends. In your case `$TARGET_CC` is wrong, and should likely be replaced with `TARGET_CC=$CC` (or something similar, depending plc the exact Makefile and build system).

Comment: In my scenario Makefile is exporting TARGET_CC variable and the Makefile is using ninja build system internally for building. I have tried with -I option for header files and -L for libraries, It fixed few compilation issue, but still failing for few linking issues of libraries. Can you guide me how to avoid the poisoning, so that the cross compiled tool chain will have similar configuration of the tool chain cross compiled in "yocto version1" of my initial post.

Comment: Look at what `$CC` is being set to. That will give you a clue as to what arguments you need to set. The best would be if you can avoid `TARGET_CC`, and have Ninja just use `CC`.

Comment: I have checked in the 3rd party source, but it is not using $CC variable in the build system. Do I need to check in Yocto, can you guide on this. I have compiled sample program with -v option to gcc, but couldn't find CC. log is @ http://pastebin.com/6wHzML29 .

Comment: Well, if you look at the paths in your latest pastebin, you'll see that some starts with `/not/exist/`.  Those are the fake paths. If you look at $CC` after sourcing the setup script for the SDK,  you'll see that there's an argument `-sysroot=... `  which corresponds to they installed location.  In your first pastebin, replace your definition of `TARGET_CC` with. `TARGET_CC=$CC`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the directory option "sysroot" with actual path to gcc then didn't give any compilation issue, but gave linking issue related to VFP updated @ http://pastebin.com/Phbf5YyS , I have checked kernel compilation logs in yocto and passed same arguments(`for -march,  -mfloat-abi, -mfpu, -mtune`), used for kernel compilation as per the logs, to gcc as updated @ http://pastebin.com/Phbf5YyS , then it was compiled successfully. In the newer versions, OpenEmbedded based build systems any changes are done so that it will poisons -march, -mfloat-abi, -mfpu, -mtune definitions.

Comment: I have modified the inc files ( @ http://pastebin.com/J2z2PBc2) to include actual sysroot path under "poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/" , after that I used that tool chain for building, now it is not giving any error for header files. But it is giving error during linking time. I have tried to create a sample shared library ( @ http://pastebin.com/J2z2PBc2 ) using this tool chain, but it is giving error related to "VFP register arguments". Can you guide how to fix this issue in the yocto tool chain configuration.

Comment: Are you building from command line, or using bitbake? Do not modify the gcc inc-files. Instead, try to get your build system use the correct flags. Ie at `TARGET_CC=$CC`, do similar things for LD, CFLAGS, etc. Otherwise, you'll need to show us the code (Makefiles, or whatever you're using).

Comment: Using bitbake for building images. The Makefile, which is using for cross compilation is [Makefile](https://github.com/legatoproject/legato-af/blob/16.01.2/Makefile.framework). The build system also using wrapper in C++ which internally calling gcc for cross compilation, so  selected the option to modify inc files related to gcc in yocto. The steps to get all layers for IMX6 yocto is updated in the initial update under `Yocto Version1:` and `Yocto Version2:`.

Comment: What wrapper? From what I can see, the Makefile calls out to cmake, to generate Makefiles for some components. It'll also call out up Ninja. Cmake is no problem, you also have a toolchain.yocto.cmake to keep you a little bit. What component fails, and wish Jane generated the makefiles used for that componen? You might have to patch the makefiles / cmake /Ninja files; that's better than patching gcc...

Comment: The make file is using three different ways (`ninja, mkexe, cmake`). By passing `TRARGET_CC=$CC` ninja build is success. [mkexe](https://github.com/legatoproject/legato-af/tree/16.01.2/framework/tools/mkTools) is a wrapper, which calls cross compiler. Not able to pass sysroot option to mkexe(so selected option to modify to modify inc files related to gcc in yocto), so hard coded the `$CC` value in [mkexe](https://github.com/legatoproject/legato-af/blob/16.01.2/framework/tools/mkTools/buildScriptGenerator/toolChain.cpp) source, after this mkexe built is success.

Comment: Now [cmake](https://github.com/legatoproject/legato-af/blob/16.01.2/Makefile.framework#L157) in the [Makefile](https://github.com/legatoproject/legato-af/blob/master/Makefile.framework) is giving [error](http://pastebin.com/NKx7BC3g). Stuck at this point, as not familiar with cmake, any guidance on fixing this cmake issue.

Comment: It looks like their Makefile.framework allows you to pass in a`LEGATO_SYSROOT`, and that you have to set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to the actual cross-compiler. I won't be able to help much more, as I won't be near a computer for the rest of the week.

Comment: By defining new variable with gcc path instead of  [TARGET_CC](https://github.com/legatoproject/legato-af/blob/master/cmake/toolchain.yocto.cmake#L18) variable and setting sysroot path for [TARGET_SYSROOT](https://github.com/legatoproject/legato-af/blob/master/cmake/toolchain.yocto.cmake#L38)  , build was success.

Comment: I have used the toolchain for creating a shared library, but it is giving ["uses VFP register arguments" error](http://pastebin.com/FHq9nJWW). Can you help me to understand why it is giving this error.

Comment: You need `-mfloat-abi=hard` as your `libfno` seems to be built that way.

Comment: Tried with `-mfloat-abi=hard` but still getting the same issue while creating [shared library](http://pastebin.com/gX9pXgna). While creating [executable](http://pastebin.com/gX9pXgna) also it is giving same issue, but if we use `-mfloat-abi=hard` the it is not giving any issue.  The error is `library(libfn.so)/executable(a.out) uses VFP register arguments, object file does not`. My doubht here is, the object files were built with the same gcc then why it is giving incompatability issue between the object file and the library/executable.

Comment: Well, if you look at `$CC` in the environment file, you'll see that it sets`-mfloat-abi=.. -mfpu=...`. You need to ensure that you pass the same arguments to the crosscompiler. (Hence, why I suggested that you fix your build system to use `$CC` and `$CXX` directly, instead of taking only a couple of pieces from them).

Comment: Is the environment file available inside yocto build environment? I searched inside yocto built with environment string, but it is giving lot of unrelated files. Can you help to understand whether environment file related to yoco build, if so where to find the file inside yocto build.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using the SDK (if so, look at the file you're sourcing). Otherwise, have a lock at e.g. `${WORKDIR}/temp/run.do_compile`, there you'll find a line like
`export CC="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 --sysroot=/mnt/poky/build-bb/tmp/sysroots/beaglebone"`.

Comment: By using $CC from run.do_compile log, [shared library created successfully](http://pastebin.com/ihdWgVp4). During my earlier post I missed `-mfloat-abi=hard` while creating object file(fn.o) and used `-mfloat-abi=hard` only while creating shared library(libfn.so), so it is giving error.