# stdint.h "no such file or directory" error on yocto sdk

Tags: cross-compiling, yocto

I'm building an System with Yocto/poky (morty branch). Building the image and the sdk works fine.

I've installed the SDK on an machine (other than the build machine) to cross compile a tool.

I've loaded the environment with

```
source /opt/mydistro/2.2.1/environment-setup-cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

Building a test file with

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.cpp
```

will fail with message

```
/opt/mydistro/2.2.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
# include_next <stdint.h>
```

Compilation with explicit sysroot

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.cpp --sysroot=/opt/mydistro/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/
```

fails with

```
... include/gnu/stubs.h:7:29: fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory ...
```

Why is this not working? What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that you can't directly use the cross-compiler is due to sysroot-poising. See [yocto built tool chain search path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673910/yocto-built-tool-chain-search-path-issue/38674457#38674457).

Thus, you should always use `$CC` instead of directly using the cross-compiler. Using `$CC` will not only specify the sysroot, but also specify things like `-march=...`, `-mfloat-abi=...`, `-mtune=...`, etc (the exact number of options is depending on what machine you're building for). That should have solved all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my case one solution to compile and link my example was to use the following command:

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/mydistro/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/ -mfloat-abi=hard
```

Comment: I don't know why the the float-abi must be explicit set to hard. My machine Build Configuration say TARGET_FPU="hard"?