# How to add sysroot option in cross-compilation?

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling

I am following [sysdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) tutorial, and have not build compiler with sysroot flag. `../binutils-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot` (forgot the last one).

So the problem is, when I have included compiler defined header `<stdint.h>` (somewhere in source, it is not important for the error), the error arise:

```
/home/user/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/8.3.0/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
 # include_next <stdint.h>
```

I have looked at the file a find:

```
...
...
# include_next <stdint.h>
...
```

1)
So why is used preprocessor macro `#include_next`, how does it differ from basic `#include`.

2)
How to solve the error of course. As the header of this question suggest, I have found this question: [stdint.h "no such file or directory" error on yocto sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187384/stdint-h-no-such-file-or-directory-error-on-yocto-sdk). There someone said, there is missing the 
3)
`sysroot`, but I have no idea what it is (whether root permission?) and how to add it in my compilation (if even) with some flag? Or need to build once again the cross compiler (but rather avoid this option). Or does it require to have special folder with the header, so it is visible for the compiler? Really do not know.

Edit:
When tried to edit the file and change the `#include_next` to just `#include`, even more error arise, so rather do not do that (have changed that back), so that macro is even more magic to me, as I saw it for the first time

Comment: Could you solve it?